# Auto sizing Div based on remaining space (accounting for following Divs)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to put some DOM together and I'm really unsure how to tackle the following problem. I essentially need to have a `.filterArea` that is visible, and for the area above it to take up the remaining space. The difficultly is I want my `.filterArea` to be responsive based on the width, and I don't know my total height up-front.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mainArea {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.filter-area .tags {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tag {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="mainArea">
  <p>
  This is the main area
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="filterArea" data-bind="component: filterComponent">
    <div class="filter-area">
      <!-- Represent the different tags that can be applied as filters -->
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag" data-tag="lessThan" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Less than</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="lessThanOrEqualTo" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Less than or equal</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="equals" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Equals</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="greaterThan" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Greater than</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="greaterThanOrEqualTo" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Greater than or equal</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="between" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Between</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
          <span class="name">and</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="within" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Within</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="empty" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Empty</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="filters scrollable numberFilters filtersEmpty" data-bind="css: filters().length === 0 ? 'filtersEmpty' : ''">
        <div data-bind="dl-filter-scroll-top:$parent"></div>
        <div data-bind="template: { foreach:filters,
                                    name: function(item) { return item.func(); },
                                    afterAdd: showFilter,
                                    beforeRemove: hideFilter  }"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've seen some solutions around but they all rely on having to know the fixed height of the `.filterArea`. Is there some CSS magic that I can apply to make the top section to resize based on the remaining space after the `.filterArea` has been processed?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "take up the remaining space"? Do you mean .mainArea and .filter-area should total  the viewport height? or?

Comment: @pivemi - yeah indeed. The combined height should take up the full viewport, but I want `.filter-area` to take priority and ensure it is visible, before `mainArea` calculates it's height.

Comment: @pivemi I'd also be interested to know, if adding an `overflow-y: scroll` on the top div (viewport) would cause any issues? It's not needed in this case, but might need scrolling for other content.

Comment: Don't think it does. Added overflow-y: scroll; to .mainArea it in the fiddle and works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **CSS flexbox** and a container that has uses the `vh` unit to make the total height the height of the viewport.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mainArea {
  background: red;
  color: white;
   flex: 1;
   
}

.filter-area .tags {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tag {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="mainArea">
  <p>
  This is the main area
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="filterArea" data-bind="component: filterComponent">
    <div class="filter-area">
      <!-- Represent the different tags that can be applied as filters -->
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag" data-tag="lessThan" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Less than</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="lessThanOrEqualTo" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Less than or equal</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="equals" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Equals</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="greaterThan" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Greater than</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="greaterThanOrEqualTo" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Greater than or equal</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="between" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Between</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg0">0</span>
          <span class="name">and</span>
          <span class="value" data-bind="dl-siformat: arg1">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="within" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Within</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tag" data-tag="empty" data-bind="click: addTag, dl-filterTagRipple">
          <span class="name">Empty</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="filters scrollable numberFilters filtersEmpty" data-bind="css: filters().length === 0 ? 'filtersEmpty' : ''">
        <div data-bind="dl-filter-scroll-top:$parent"></div>
        <div data-bind="template: { foreach:filters,
                                    name: function(item) { return item.func(); },
                                    afterAdd: showFilter,
                                    beforeRemove: hideFilter  }"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You know you can add stack overflow snippets to answers? Rather than having to link to JSFiddle too?

Comment: I didn't until now. Only joined a couple days ago. Thanks :)

Comment: I've updated your answer with a snippet instead - that actually applies to my individual question. Thank you for your help - stackoverflow points for you! :)